# Отправка сообщений от имени сообщества

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, вконтакте

Я знаю, что с 2019 апи сообщений закрыли. Вопрос: распространяется ли это на группы? (я бота для вк пишу). Если да, то какие обходы сего чуда природы на данный момент существуют?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, на группы это не распространяется. Вам нужно включить сообщения сообщества и получить ключ доступа к API.

Вот здесь есть небольшая инструкция, может быть, окажется полезной: [Статья на Хабре про ботов вк](https://habr.com/ru/post/326312/)